# Only I can access my hosted website!

Tags: web-hosting, dns, cpanel

**Problem Background**

I have bought a domain from `bigrock.com` and hosted website on their server.

Initially, I was not able to access my site with its name e.g.: `www.sitename.com`, but it was accessable with its IP address. So I wrote to BigRock about that, they told me that "Your site is working fine for them" and they gave me screenshot with name.

I got confused, so my friend suggested to change the DNS server address in my router with Google's DNS servers name (`8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`), I did it and I was able to access my website with its name.

**Problem Starts**

Now my website is done and live but **many people are not able to access it, only few doesn't face problem**.
I cannot tell everyone to update their routers with Google's DNS server names!

I again wrote to BigRock about it, but they are again saying "Your website is working fine!"

How do I solve this problem? Am I missing some configuration in CPanel? Is it in my scope? or shall I move to another Web-Hosting provider?

**UPDATE: 1**
One month have elapsed I have registered my domain hosted it.
I was developing it from a month. (Updating it with FileZilla daily)

**UPDATE: 2**
Domain Name: [www.nistnu.in](http://www.nistnu.in)

Tested on : http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/

**Errors:**

Delegation not found at parent.

No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet.

Not enough nameserver information was found to test the zone www.nistnu.in, but an IP address lookup succeeded in spite of that.

Comment: This question has been answered (and accepted).  It is so specific to your situation that it is unlikely to be very informative for future visitors -- closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue: It takes time for DNS information to propagate throughout the Internet to different DNS servers. Some update more frequently than others, are closer in distance, have more resources (e.g., Google), etc...

Your web hosting company can view the site because they're on the same network and DNS servers. The others that can also view it probably have DNS servers that were updated. I would give it at least 24 hours (up to 72 hours) for DNS changes to propagate fully.

After that time, you can check online DNS testing sites, like [Pingdom Tools](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/) to verify that your site is reachable and its DNS configuration is correct. You can also use different Ping and webpage speed tests to verify that your site can be reached. Pingdom Tools has an "Advanced" option under the "Full Page Test" tab to check from different geographical locations too.

Comment: Thankyou for replying dan, but now its more than one month I have registered my domain. Quite big time for all DNS servers to have my site's entry with them. For a month, website was in development.

Comment: I had coincidentally just added a link to test its DNS configuration. Here's another: http://network-tools.com/
That ought to give you some clues. Yes, it should only take a few days for DNS settings to be visible everywhere. I see you added an update that it's been a month.

Comment: If don't mind sharing your domain, I can have a look at for you.

Comment: My domain name is www.nistnu.in, I have  tested with Pingdom Tools, it gave errors.. I have updated the error messages in my Question, please check. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, now we're getting somewhere :-) Your site loaded pretty quickly on my end, and has a fast ping response time and traceroute. It seems like there's some issue with your nameservers and DNS records. Is it possible for you to copy your DNS table into your answer?

Comment: Yes, but not at this moment, m now in office, will post when I am home after 6-7 hrs.. You gave me clue, now I feel that it is in my scope :) Thank you Dan.

Comment: Here's a guide that may help setting your nameservers in cPanel:
http://etwiki.cpanel.net/twiki/pub/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/DNSNewbieGuide.pdf

Comment: sure I will try it and will let you know!

Comment: I would contact your web hosting company again however, and if not happy, I could recommend using GoDaddy because I know they have support numbers in India, are very responsive about issues like this, and reachable by phone 24 hours a day. Good luck!

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe you can accept my answer if I did. BTW, your site looks nice. Hope you get your DNS problems sorted out and have good success with it when you do.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :), and yes, u helped alot. Also, I read your answers of other questions, they are awesome! I learned from them!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's rewarding to share what you know with others. It makes you feel smarter too :-) I'll keep an eye on your site, it has a very clean, appealing design. Good job.

Comment: Yes, It is built with OpenCart, you maybe already knowing that! and More Sharing is More Gaining too!