# Transferring a domain that is managed by Cloudflare to another registrar

Tags: cloudflare, domain-transfer

I'm planning on switching from OVH to Gandi in the coming weeks/months (domain first, hosting later). However, I'm not sure what the process is exactly, given I'm also using Cloudflare and none of the guides I found seem to address this particular case.

The point I'm unsure about is whether I actually need to do anything regarding Cloudflare. Do I need to pause my website on Cloudflare and change the name servers back to OVH's before the transfer, or can I just leave that as is and then set Cloudflare's nameservers in Gandi's configuration once the transfer is done?

[This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49239/88253) makes me think I can just leave everything as is and do the transfer, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have done this numerous times and can confirm Steve's answer is correct. If Cloudflare is handling your DNS, you're free to transfer your hosting to where ever you like. You only need to change the IP address to your new server in the `A` record in Cloudflare, along with any other records that display the old IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nameservers remain unchanged when you transfer a domain from one registrar (or reseller) to another.  So if you are using Cloudflare nameservers and everything is working, it should continue to work when your domain is transferred.

Although this isn't the case with you, to add information to this answer: Do be mindful that DNS settings are not transferred when nameservers are changed.  So if you have custom records, they will need to be set up at the new hosting service.

Comment: Great! So just to clarify, there's no need to even disable/pause Cloudflare beforehand?

Comment: A bad metaphor is to think of it like being on the phone to someone and passing it to a friend to chat.  You don't have to hang up first.

Answer (score 0):

You should only update your settings in CloudFlare when you change your hosting.  Reason being that by changing your hosting provider, you'll need to update the IP address that CloudFlare has on file to reflect the new server's IP.